# Edit and Save in Lotus Notes web form

Tags: javascript, web, lotus-notes

We have a web form built on Lotus Notes. In this form we want a button Save which on click will save the form and not close the form. So that the users must be able to edit and save without closing the form. How can this be done?

Comment: Please show your code. How does your current button "Save and Close" look like?

Comment: we have a check() function which checks the validations and then it document.forms[0].submit(); but it submits the document and then closes the document. Is it possible not to close the document after it saves.

Comment: This is normally done by submitting the document normally and having the WebQuerySave agent print a redirection URL (surrounded by square brackets) that re-opens the document for editing. Of course, this actually closes and re-opens the form and the user will lose their position unless you add a script and a URL argument to restore focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a save function using Javascript (or even easier use jQuery).
You can call a simple Lotusscript agent to save the form values into the document.

I will do a presentation about this at MWLUG in Austin in August, but you can find sample code in my previous presentations here:

http://blog.texasswede.com/mwlug-2015/ - also includes the basics of Ajax, JSON, jQuery and Bootstrap

http://blog.texasswede.com/my-connect-2016-presentation-demo-database/ - my presentation from IBM Connect 2016, shorter and less focused on the basics,  showing how to use JSONP to call agents on other servers.

Here is how you can do it:

1) Give all input fields a custom attribut called notes-field, set it to the name of the field in the Domino database. It should look something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" notes-field="FirstName">
```

Also make sure you store the Notes doucument UNID (Unique ID) of the document you are editing in a HTML element. I store it as a data attribute in a DIV with the ID of docUNID, like this:

```
<div id="docUNID" data-UNID="CD8808D24664739A86257FB7005B38CE">
```

2) Bind the following jQuery code to your save button:

```
// Get Document UNID for the document you want to update
var docunid =  $("#docUNID").attr("data-UNID");
var json = new Object();
// Store field values in JSON object
json["DocUNID"] = docunid;
$('input[notes-field]').each( function() {
    var notesfield = $(this).attr("notes-field");
    json[notesfield] = $(this).val();
});
// Perform Ajax call to the server to save values            
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/path/database.nsf/ajax_SaveContact.jsonp?OpenAgent", 
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: json
});
```

3) Create a callback function that will handle the data returned by the SaveData agent. This function name have to match the one in your agent that you will create in the next step.

```
// Call-back function for save contact call
function callbackSaveContact(data) {
     if (data.ajaxstatus=="error") {
        alert("Failure: " + data.msg);
    } else if (data.ajaxstatus=="success") {
        alert("Success: " + data.msg);
    }
}
```

4) Create your agent to save the data passed to it into the specified document:

```
%REM
    Agent ajax_SaveContact.jsonp
    Created Dec 24, 2015 by Karl-Henry Martinsson
    Description: Save contact details, return status 
    and informational message as JSONP
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare

Use "Class.JSON"
Use "Class.URL"

Sub Initialize
    '--- Local Notes classes used in agent
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    '--- Custom classes
    Dim json As JSONData
    Dim url As New URLData

    '*** Get document
    Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
    If url.GetValue("DocUNID")<>"" Then
        Set doc = db.GetDocumentByUNID(url.GetValue("DocUNID"))
    End If
    '*** Check that we found a document, otherwise create a new person document
    If doc Is Nothing Then
        Set doc = New NotesDocument(db)
        doc.Form = "Person"
        Call doc.Save(True,False)
        Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("DocUNID", doc.UniversalID)
    End If
    ForAll v In url.values()
        Call doc.ReplaceItemValue(ListTag(v),v)
    End ForAll
    Call doc.Save(True,False)
    Set json = New JSONData()
    json.success = True
    json.SetMsg("Saved " + url.GetValue("FirstName") + " " + url.GetValue("LastName"))
    Call json.SetValue("DocUNID", doc.UniversalID)
    Call json.SendJSONPToBrowser("callbackSaveContact")
End Sub
```

Note that you need to use two script libraries, each containing a custom class. The first one Class.URL is used to read the data passed in the HTTP POST/GET coming in to the agent. The second one Class.JSON helps you create the JSON/JSONP to return. 
You can find them in the sample databases for my presentations as well as on my blog:

http://blog.texasswede.com/free-code-class-to-read-url-name-value-pairs/
http://blog.texasswede.com/calling-a-notes-web-agent-from-another-server-using-jsonp/

The presentations are also on SlideShare.net:

http://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/ibm-connect-2016-break-out-of-the-box

http://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/ad102-break-out-of-the-box